# How to know Text Completion in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, textview, autocompletetextview

I just want to call a method after Text Completion in AutoCompleteTextView. It is not possible to put the method in side afterTextChanged, it is calling method continuously according to the text change. I want to call the method only once on Text Completion. How can i do this.. Please help...

Comment: Are you using CustomAutoCompleteTextView widget

Comment: Its AutoCompleteTextView with SimpleAdapter to show the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private CustomAutoCompleteTextView mAutoFillTextView;
mAutoFillTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String string = s.toString().trim();
        if (mAutoFillTextView.getThreshold() <= string.length() && mAllowRequest) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OK : " + string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (string.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OK : " + string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```